# could not find driver in PDO_FIREBIRD using PHP

Tags: php, apache, connection, firebird

I am getting Error: Could not find Driver while connecting to Firebird DB using PHP. My driver setting in PHP.INI file are OK with enabled extensions. It is showing PDO_firebird clicked. I have also copied firebirdclient dll file in system32 folder. tried doing anything i can but still its showing the same error. My firebird db file is in the same location. port for locathost access is 85. Anyone's help will be really obliged. Code i am writting with the help of some suggestion is as under:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost:c:/xpos_db/';
$username = 'sysdba';
$password = 'masterkey';
$db = 'xposdata.fdb';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("firebird:host=$server;dbname=$db", $username, 
    $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected Successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Problemo!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please look at the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.connection.php): the connection string is wrong, it should be `firebird:dbname=localhost:c:/xpos_db/xposdata.fdb`, not `firebird:host=localhost:c:/xpos_db/;dbname=xposdata.fdb` (and even if those properties both exist, the values would be wrong). If the error still occurs, make sure you post the full error here.

Comment: Also, manually copying `fbclient.dll` into system32 is the wrong thing to do: use the client installer. And make sure to install the right bitness: for a 64 bit PHP, install the 64 bit fbclient, for 32 bit, the 32 bit one.